# JsHint (W083): Don't make functions within a loop. - Using [].forEach();

Tags: javascript, jshint, eslint

I get this error:

> JsHint (W083): Don't make functions within a loop.

when using the following code:

```
for (var prop in cmd.properties) {
  Object.keys(meta[prop].data).forEach(function (rule) {
    rules.data[rule] = meta[prop].data[rule] ? true : false;
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Basically I am looping through properties of an object `meta[prop].data` and for each property, I am setting true/false other another object properties using a `ternary` operator.

Reading some documentation I see:

> JSHint and ESLint encounter a function expression in a for, while or
>   do statement body.

- Is this error legitimate one?
- If yes, how to better re-write these lines?
- If no, how to disable this specific error validation using JsHint?

Comment: Are you sure this code is not inside a loop...?

Comment: @Juhana thanks for your edit, I have made an edit to my original question.

Comment: Well, ok, after the edit it's clear it's a legit error because you are in fact making a function inside a loop.

Comment: Not sure, could please post an answer with your revised version? I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Hint - don't make functions within a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082302/js-hint-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop)

Comment: You could use `forEach` again to replace the for loop, also what's the use of `bind(this)` ? (as you don't use `this` in your function)

Comment: I am using this in my working code, but thanks all for pointing out the cost of bind().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this error legitimate one?

Yes, you're declaring a function within a loop. On top of that, `bind` can be pretty expensive, since it has to create a new lexical scope every time and return a "new" function attached to that scope.

> If yes, how to better re-write these lines?

If you can, declare the function before the loop and either bind once or use simple closure to avoid an explicit bind call:

```
var scope = this;
var ruleFunc = function (rule) {
  rules.data[rule] = meta[prop].data[rule] ? true : false;
}

for (var prop in cmd.properties) {
  Object.keys(meta[prop].data).forEach(ruleFunc);
}
```

I don't see where you're using `this` within the function, though, so you may be able to remove it entirely:

```
var ruleFunc = function (rule) {
  rules.data[rule] = meta[prop].data[rule] ? true : false;
}

for (var prop in cmd.properties) {
  Object.keys(meta[prop].data).forEach(ruleFunc);
}
```

Both of these will require refactoring your code, since you're using closure to grab the `prop` variable from the loop. You can use `bind` to work around that, with a performance hit:

```
var ruleFunc = function (prop, rule) {
  rules.data[rule] = meta[prop].data[rule] ? true : false;
}

for (var prop in cmd.properties) {
  Object.keys(meta[prop].data).forEach(ruleFunc.bind(this, prop));
}
```

You're also using a conditional to return `true`/`false`, which is a common smell. You typically want to convert that to a boolean, with `!!` being the idiomatic JS way:

```
rules.data[rule] = !!(meta[prop].data[rule]);
```

If you can, avoiding `for ... in` loops will usually make your life better, so you may want to refactor that as well:

```
Object.keys(cmd.properties).forEach(function (prop) {
  Object.keys(meta[prop].data).forEach(function (rule) {
    rules.data[rule] = !!(meta[prop].data);
  });
});
```

You may be able to improve that further still.

Comment: "avoiding `for ... in` loops will usually make your life better" - that is a funny comment, given that the warning about the possible issue (that, if I understand the reasons correctly, should not be an issue here at all and can be safely ignored) is only there *because* a `for ... in` loop was avoided (for the inner loop) in favour of a call to `forEach`.