# Referencing an outer scoped variable on a loop within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m getting a JSHint/JSLint error on my code below.

`Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. ($, currentVal)`

This is directed at the `$options.each` loop where I’m pushing to `currentVal`.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

```
$(".option input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  reload_filterstring(this);
});

$(".option input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  reload_filterstring(this);
});

function reload_filterstring(that) {
  var finalFilterQuery = {};

  var currentEl = "";

  (filterType = $this.attr("data-filter-type")),
  ($options = $this.find("ul.options input")),
  (query = $this.find('input[name="query"]')),
  (finalQuery = $('input[name="finalQuery"]')),
  (filterData = []),
  (filterQuery = null);

//  console.log(filterName);

currentVal = [];

$options.each(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    currentVal.push($(this).attr("id"));
  }
});

finalFilterQuery[filterName] = currentVal.join("|");
  }

  // console.log(finalFilterQuery);
  var str = "";
  for (var key in finalFilterQuery) {
if (finalFilterQuery.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if (str != "") {
    str += ",";
  }
  str += key + "=" + finalFilterQuery[key];
}
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drMRem?editors=1111

Comment: You should definetly declare `currentVal`.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the closing `}` for `reload_filterstring()`

Comment: Why are you using so many global variables? And assign to them in such a way with grouping and comma operators? Use variable declarations instead.

Comment: a) declare `$` as global b) use `Array.from($options).filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.id).join("|");`

Comment: @Bergi Isn’t that still a function? I won’t be using arrow functions.

Comment: @JohnthePainter Not sure what you mean "still a function"? And of course you can use normal function expressions if you don't like arrow functions for some weird reason.

Comment: Well arrow functions are a function so using them in the loop would still return the same error, no?

Answer (score -1):

I ran with codepen.io JS Analyse and the result was: **Don't make functions within a loop.** with a link to this [JS Hint - don't make functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082302/js-hint-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop). You should move the function out instead of placing it inside a loop, but if you still insist on having a function inside the loop, you can narrow down the scope of currentVal inside the function like below:

```html
$options.each(function($currentVal) {
  return function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $currentVal.push($(this).attr("id"));
    };
  }(currentVal));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I’m unsure how my code will work correctly without the function (loop) within a loop.

Comment: "*Don't make functions within a loop.*" - uh, the OPs code doesn't do that?